# Auto increment by 2 starting from 1000

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I’m using MySQL to make a table:

```
CREATE TABLE school.student(
    Std_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Std_name CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Std_Birth DATE,
    Std_Group CHAR(2) check(Std_Group in ('G1', 'G2','G3','G4'))
);
```

And I’m trying to make the auto increment start from 1000 and increment by two (1000, 1002, 1004, 1006, etc.) while using CREATE.

Comment: What means *without changing the default auto_increment_increment and auto increment offset* ? You can't have the default (staring 1 incrment by 1) and your customer autoincrement at same time and same column

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO _students
(Std_id, Std_name, Std_Birth, Std_Group)
select case when count(Std_id) >= 1 then max(Std_id) + 2 else 1000 end as Std_id, 'test', '2022-10-10', 'G1'
from _students;
```

`select case when count(Std_id) >= 1 then max(Std_id) + 2 else 1000 end`: this will check if there are any records in your table. If not, it will insert the first with id 1000.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #autoincre
(
    Std_id int not null Primary key identity (1000,2),
    Std_name char(40) Not null,
    Std_Birth date,
    Std_Group char(2) check(Std_group in ('G1','G2','G3','G4'))
)

Drop table #autoincre

insert into #autoincre values('Ajay','2022-07-10','G1')

select * from #autoincre
```

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Server syntax, not MySQL. MySQL doesn't support the Microsoft function `identity()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution:

```
CREATE TABLE school.student(
    Std_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Std_name CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Std_Birth DATE,
    Std_Group CHAR(2) check(Std_Group in ('G1', 'G2','G3','G4'))
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;

set @@auto_increment_increment=2;
```

- while you set the value of **@@auto_increment_increment**, it will
  affect all over the database. Because, it's a *global* variable for
  MySQL.
- For setting the starting value from 1000, you may need to set
  **AUTO_INCREMENT** at the end of the **Create Table** syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the auto_increment for a given table at 1000 with a table option:

```
CREATE TABLE school.student(
 ...
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Note that the next id generated will be one greater than the table option is set to, so it will generate value 1001. If you want it to include the value 1000, set the table option `AUTO_INCREMENT=999`.

Your other requirement is more difficult.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-source.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment says:

> It is not possible to restrict the effects of these two variables to a single table; these variables control the behavior of all AUTO_INCREMENT columns in *all* tables on the MySQL server.

In other words, if you set `auto_increment_increment=2`, this will apply to all tables with an auto-increment column. It is not a per-table option.

You could set `auto_increment_increment=2` as a session variable only before inserting into the student table, then set it back to the default before inserting to another table. That sounds like it will be error-prone, because you could forget to change the session variable.